# How to debug when lacking details

Tags: php, debugging, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I am  getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException' with message 'Entity was not found.' in D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 1382

Doctrine\ORM\EntityNotFoundException: Entity was not found. in D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 1382

Call Stack:
   16.4461     329328   1. {main}() D:\Websites\Tickle\public\index.php:0
   20.4544    1417216   2. Zend_Application->run() D:\Websites\Tickle\public\index.php:26
   20.4544    1417216   3. Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run() D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Application.php:366
   20.4546    1417272   4. Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch(???, ???) D:\ResourceLibrary\Frameworks\PHPFrameworks\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php:97
```

From the stack trace, the files shown in mainly framework classes, not my code where the error most probably is. How can I find out where in my code last triggered the error? I tried using Netbeans + XDebug, but it was a very long step through, its hard to see where in my code triggers the error. How will you recommend I start?

I currently am trying to use Screenr to record my step through, so I can trace the last 1 or 2 mins b4 the error ...

It appears that it seems to run my controllers & layout ok, when I put `die('ok ...');` in IndexController::indexAction & at the end of layout.phtml. its ok. So whats run after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Netbeans set a breakpoint in that file and line, UnitOfWork.php on line 1382. Then run a debug session, recreate the request to trigger the bug, and when it hits your breakpoint you can see how it got there via the call stack, as well as what variables were passed around. This should start you off investigating what went wrong.

Comment: ah... why didn't I think of that ... I was only thinking of putting break points in *my* code!